# Chrome or web is not working in flutter 2.05 keep giving so much errors and failed to compile

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, pubspec

keep trying to open chrome in flutter, before it was working now every time I try to run it it throws many errors in the terminal then says failed to compile.

please help, iOS and android is working fine tried in beta master and stable release always throws all these errors below:
There was 75,000 errors but i could only add 30,000
please help... there must be a way around this

i am using flutter 2.0.5

```
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<CREDENTIAL_ATTRIBUTE> Attributes;
                                         ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:265:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> TargetAlias;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:266:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> UserName;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:275:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> Keyword;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:277:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int Flags;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:279:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ValueSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:280:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Uint8> Value;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:287:29: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<VARIANT> rgvarg;
                            ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:288:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Int32> rgdispidNamedArgs;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:290:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cArgs;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:292:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cNamedArgs;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:301:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cbSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:303:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMajorVersion;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:305:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMinorVersion;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:307:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwBuildNumber;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:309:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwPlatformID;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:318:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cbSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:320:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int iTabLength;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:322:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int iLeftMargin;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:324:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int iRightMargin;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:326:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uiLengthDrawn;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:335:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwLowDateTime;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:337:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwHighDateTime;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:347:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:349:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwICC;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:356:21: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external SHITEMID mkid;
                    ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:364:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int category;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:365:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszName;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:366:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszDescription;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:367:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external GUID fidParent;
                ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:368:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszRelativePath;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:369:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszParsingName;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:370:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszTooltip;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:371:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszLocalizedName;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:372:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszIcon;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:373:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> pszSecurity;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:375:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwAttributes;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:377:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int kfdFlags;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:378:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external GUID ftidType;
                ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:388:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int lbStyle;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:390:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int lbColor;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:392:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int lbHatch;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:401:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwCallback;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:403:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwFrom;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:405:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwTo;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:414:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwCallback;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:416:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwReturn;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:418:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwItem;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:420:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwTrack;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:428:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cbSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:430:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int fMask;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:432:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwStyle;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:434:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cyMax;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:436:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int hbrBack;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:438:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwContextHelpID;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:440:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMenuData;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:448:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cbSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:450:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.  
  external int fMask;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:452:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int fType;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:454:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int fState;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:456:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wID;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:458:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int hSubMenu;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:460:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.  
  external int hbmpChecked;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:462:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int hbmpUnchecked;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:464:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwItemData;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:465:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> dwTypeData;
                          ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:467:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cch;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:469:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int hbmpItem;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:477:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT ptReserved;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:478:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT ptMaxSize;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:479:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT ptMaxPosition;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:480:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT ptMinTrackSize;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:481:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:489:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ssize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:491:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ssig;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:492:20: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer data;
                   ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:494:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int size;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:496:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int flags;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:504:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int cbSize;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:505:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external RECT rcMonitor;
                ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:506:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external RECT rcWork;
                ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:508:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwFlags;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:516:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int x;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:518:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int y;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:520:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int time;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:522:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwExtraInfo;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:530:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int hwnd;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:532:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int message;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:534:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wParam;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:536:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int lParam;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:538:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int time;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:539:18: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external POINT pt;
                 ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:549:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int peRed;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:551:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int peGreen;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:553:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int peBlue;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:555:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.  
  external int peFlags;
               ^
/C:/Users/sshiekh/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.0.5/lib/src/structs.g.dart:563:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int x;
               ^
     
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...            167.2s
Failed to compile application.
```

Comment: I got this error while using moor in web,I had to remove "import 'package:moor/ffi.dart';"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it resolved. I had to insert
in my pubspec folder.
ffi: ^1.1.2