# Converting the Flutter app to Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert my Flutter app to Flutter web app. I am facing this issue. This is giving me the error on running `flutter run -d chrome`. What does this `"Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation."` means here?

App is perfectly running fine. What is `JS interop annotation`?

```
external int dot11BssType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7011:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> dot11Bssid;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7014:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11PhyType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7017:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uDot11PhyIndex;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7020:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanSignalQuality;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7023:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulRxRate;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7026:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulTxRate;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7035:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7038:42: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<DOT11_AUTH_CIPHER_PAIR> pAuthCipherPairList;
                                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7047:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint16> _strProfileName;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7065:23: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external DOT11_SSID dot11Ssid;
                      ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7068:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11BssType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7071:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uNumberOfBssids;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7074:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bNetworkConnectable;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7077:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanNotConnectableReason;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7080:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uNumberOfPhyTypes;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7083:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Int32> dot11PhyTypes;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7086:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bMorePhyTypes;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7089:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanSignalQuality;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7092:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bSecurityEnabled;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7095:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7098:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7101:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwFlags;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7104:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwReserved;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7113:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7116:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwIndex;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7119:42: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK> Network;
                                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7127:23: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external DOT11_SSID dot11Ssid;
                      ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7130:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uPhyId;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7133:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> dot11Bssid;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7136:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11BssType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7139:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11BssPhyType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7142:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int lRssi;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7145:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int uLinkQuality;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7148:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bInRegDomain;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7151:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int usBeaconPeriod;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7154:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ullTimestamp;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7157:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ullHostTimestamp;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7160:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int usCapabilityInformation;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7163:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulChCenterFrequency;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7165:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external WLAN_RATE_SET wlanRateSet;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7168:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulIeOffset;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7171:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulIeSize;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7180:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwTotalSize;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7183:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7186:34: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<WLAN_BSS_ENTRY> wlanBssEntries;
                                 ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7195:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int isState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7198:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanConnectionMode;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7201:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint16> _strProfileName;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7219:40: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external WLAN_ASSOCIATION_ATTRIBUTES wlanAssociationAttributes;
                                       ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7221:37: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external WLAN_SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES wlanSecurityAttributes;
                                    ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7230:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanConnectionMode;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7233:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint16> _strProfileName;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7251:23: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external DOT11_SSID dot11Ssid;
                      ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7254:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11BssType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7257:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bSecurityEnabled;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7260:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanReasonCode;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7263:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwFlags;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7266:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint16> _strProfileXml;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7291:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int wlanConnectionMode;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7293:27: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<Utf16> strProfile;
                          ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7295:32: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<DOT11_SSID> pDot11Ssid;
                               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7297:38: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Pointer<DOT11_BSSID_LIST> pDesiredBssidList;
                                     ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7300:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11BssType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7303:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwFlags;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7312:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7315:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> pCountryOrRegionStringList;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7323:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7326:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwIndex;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7329:24: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<GUID> DeviceService;
                       ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7336:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external GUID DeviceService;
                ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7339:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwOpCode;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7342:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwDataSize;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7345:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> DataBlob;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7354:23: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external DOT11_SSID hostedNetworkSSID;
                      ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7357:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMaxNumberOfPeers;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7366:43: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE OldState;
                                          ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7368:43: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE NewState;
                                          ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7371:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int PeerStateChangeReason;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7380:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> PeerMacAddress;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7383:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int PeerAuthState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7392:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11SoftwareRadioState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7395:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11HardwareRadioState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7404:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11AuthAlgo;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7407:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11CipherAlgo;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7416:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int OldState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7419:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int NewState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7422:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int StateChangeReason;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7431:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int HostedNetworkState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7433:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external GUID IPDeviceID;
                ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7436:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint8> wlanHostedNetworkBSSID;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7439:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dot11PhyType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7442:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ulChannelFrequency;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7445:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfPeers;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7448:50: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE> PeerList;
                                                 ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7457:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int interfaceType;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7460:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int bDot11DSupported;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7463:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMaxDesiredSsidListSize;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7466:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwMaxDesiredBssidListSize;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7469:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfSupportedPhys;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7472:25: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Int32> dot11PhyTypes;
                        ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7480:17: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external GUID InterfaceGuid;
                ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7483:26: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<Uint16> _strInterfaceDescription;
                         ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7502:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int isState;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7511:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwNumberOfItems;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7514:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int dwIndex;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7517:39: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external Array<WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO> InterfaceInfo;
                                      ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7526:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ullTransmittedFrameCount;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7529:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ullReceivedFrameCount;
               ^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/win32-2.6.1/lib/src/structs.g.dart:7532:16: Error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'.
Try removing the 'external' keyword or adding a JS interop annotation.
  external int ullWEPExcludedCount;
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app running on web failing with error: Only JS interop members may be 'external'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368754/flutter-app-running-on-web-failing-with-error-only-js-interop-members-may-be-e)

Comment: Also, try checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126771/chrome-or-web-is-not-working-in-flutter-2-05-keep-giving-so-much-errors-and-fail

Comment: No these links did not work for me. I am getting 1000s of errors while converting my app to web app.

Comment: Check if all your dependencies support the web platform. As I can see form the error message, win32 is a window-only package.